# adding script within a command

Tags: python, maya

```
cmds.cmds.floatField(speed,v=True)
number = cmds.floatField(speed,q=True,v=True)
cmds.dynExpression('nparticles1',s = 'lifespanPP =  number',c = 1)
```

The above expression does not work as it keeps giving me an error 
"value number does not exists"
Anyone know how to get around this..?
This is for the Maya nParticles PerParticle Attributes.

I cannot get rid of the  ( '' )  marks as then it gives me an error "invalid syntax"

Comment: You've completely changed the previous question. This edit should be an entirely NEW question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `number` is a python object, but you're trying to put it in a (`MEL`) expression. `MEL` can't see it. Fortunately it's just a string, so you can format it into the expression like this:

```
cmds.cmds.floatField(speed,v=True)
number = cmds.floatField(speed,q=True,v=True)
expression = 'lifespanPP = "{0}"'.format(number)
cmds.dynExpression('nparticles1', s=expression, c=1)
```

You don't *need* to put the expression on a new line, but it makes it easier to read

Comment: is there a way i can do this         cmds.dynExpression('nparticles1',s = 'mass = 10',expression,c=1)  it keeps giving me a syntax error!

Comment: positional arguments always need to be before named arguments: `cmds.dynExpression('nparticles1',expression,s='mass= 10',c=1)`

Comment: Im sorry for these stupid questions,But im new to this                                                        speedvalue = particleforsim + '.'+'speed2'                                                                speedcontroll = '\nif(character == 0){\ncustomindex = rand(16,31);\ncustomspeed ={0};\n}'.format(speedvalue)        this gives me  a Key error any idea why...???

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but this is far too hard to read in a comment. You should ask it as a new question

Comment: @Arnvfx, that's not what I asked for :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and editing my question again.You really saved me hours of mistakes